# Free GIT Server with Web GUI a la BitBucket/GitHub

Tags: linux, git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

At work I am working with BitBucket. I want something like that for at home to deploy on my Linux Server. So I am looking for:

- Only **1 or 2 users** needed.
- An **GIT Server** deployable on **Linux**
- A **Fancy Web GUI** to visualize branches and do other operations (creating repos, branches, merging, statistics).
- **Well documented** how to get this all running on Linux/Ubuntu.
- **Free/Low Cost.**

What are my options. I found so far BitBucket Server for $10/year. What are other options?

Answer (score 5):

I would give gitlab a try, the Omnibus package is easy to install and it works fine here:

https://about.gitlab.com/

Answer (score 3):

1. You can do ssh + [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html). No web interface, just pure git. For web interface use [gitweb](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/gitweb) or [cgit](http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/about/).
2. Or [Klaus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/klaus) — a WSGI server with both web interface and git smart HTTP transport.
3. [Kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/).
4. [pagure](https://pagure.io/)
5. http://gitprep.yukikimoto.com/
6. https://gogs.io/
7. https://gitbucket.github.io/gitbucket-news/about/
8. https://rocketgit.com/

Comment: No consideration of gitlab?

Comment: It's been mentioned in all the other answers. :-)

Comment: You should probably try to make your list more exhaustive by adding it, just because other answers have mentioned it doesn't mean it isn't worthy of a mention. Your answer should answer the question to the best of your ability/knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

[Gitlab Community Edition](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce) is definitely a viable option that meets your need. Especially if you want issue tracking, simple project management and CI all in one package. Lately GitLab CE is becoming a larger, more resource intensive product as they add these new features. Integrations with external tools such as Jenkins are often not as seamless as they are with Bitbucket server, GitHub or Bitbucket.org.

You could also consider [Bitbucket server](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server), it's $10 for a 10 user license. If you're familiar with the UI then it may work for you. The plugin eco-system is considerable, with many plugins to meet your needs.

[Gogs](https://gogs.io/) is also worth considering.