# How to publish local git repository online

Tags: git, virtualhost, webmin

I would like to ask how can I able to put my local git server online.

Scenario:
I have my git residing in a virtual machine server (CentOS) along with it are a bunch of virtual host c/o webmin. And i also have public dns ready be setup for this.

Can I use webmin to carry git files over online?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44239764/7976758

Answer (score 1):

If by "carrying git files server" online, you mean push them to a visible public repo, all you need is:

- internet access from your VM
- Git itself (no "server" feature required), which you can install through webmin.

This (pushing to an external public repo) is easier than setting up a server (https or ssh) for your Git repo to be accessible.