# Invalid Permission for Git Pull on Debian VM

Tags: linux, git, debian

I have this Debian VM on Google where I can't git pull even when I'm included in the group with permission to wrx.

So here are the specifics:

- the error returned by git pull is `error: cannot update the ref 'refs/remote/origin/my-branch': Permission Denied`
- git directory has 775 permission
- git directory is owned by www-data:my-group
- git pull works when I change the ownership to my-username:my-group
- can't have myself as the owner of the git directory as www-data needs ownership to write
- the git repo is a CodeIgniter 3 project
- VM uses php7.4

Note:

- I've checked my-group with "getent group my-group" and can see my-username there

Comment: i wouldn't be surprised if you have mixed permissions inside that repo. Check permissions on that file specifically to make sure (`.git/refs/remotes/origin/branch-name`). If the file does not exist, then the problem is probably on the permissions for directory `.git/refs/remotes/origin`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Did you run `git` as `root` before?

Comment: Make the repo group-shareable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193032/7976758 . Set `umask 002` for user `www-data`.

Comment: Sharing a Git directory with a group seems like a weird attempt to use Git and very probably an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The trivial and obvious solution is to have your own working copy, and push to a shared repo when you wish to share changes.

Comment: @tripleee How to allow for a few different users to push over SSH without giving them full permissions of the destination user `www-data`?

Comment: Don't host under `www-data`?

Comment: @tripleee The OP rejected this already: "*can't have myself as the owner of the git directory as www-data needs ownership to write*"

Comment: That doesn't mean the repo has to be owned by `www-data`.

Comment: @tripleee So group-sharing is still the answer? :-)

Comment: Well no; a better solution is to use a tool which controls access properly, as you [are no doubt aware.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47907875/874188)

Answer (score 0):

[eftshift0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76224987/invalid-permission-for-git-pull-on-debian-vm#comment134421203_76224987) solved the issue

> i wouldn't be surprised if you have mixed permissions inside that repo. Check permissions on that file specifically to make sure (`.git/refs/remotes/origin/branch-name`). If the file does not exist, then the problem is probably on the permissions for directory `.git/refs/remotes/origin`

Somehow the grp ownership of some files inside .git changed since the last time I checked. A quick `chmod -R 775` solved the issue.

Comment: Instead of citing my comment in your answer you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76224987/edit) and replace the screenshot with pasted text, formatted as a code block. If the group *ownership* would have change, you would have to use `chown` or `chgrp` instead of `chmod`. If "somehow" the permissions changed you should find out what caused this change. Maybe a wrong configuration somewhere related to your web server?