# How to restrict push to the branch?

Tags: git

We have our server implementation of git repo. I would like to restrict push to the one of the branch of the repo for everyone except of me.

So, I added under `.git/hooks/update` on server git dir such script

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$USER" != "Aleksey" ] && [ "$1" == refs/heads/test_br ];then
echo "Manual pushing to this repo is restricted"
exit 1
fi
```

And I see that condition `"$USER" != "Aleksey"` is always `true`. Second condition looks like is work good, but name condition not...

Who know what is the problem? Maybe I need to compare with user mail? Or something else?

Feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

`git` doesn't have any notion of users. Whatever protocol you use to push to remote `$USER` is the user under which server-side `git` operates. For example if you push like `git push git@remote-server/repo.git` then `$USER` is always *git*.

If you want user-based branch protection you need to install something that has a notion of users — [gitolite, github, gitlab, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246093/7976758).

Comment: but because of we have the remote server implementation of git I can't install something to additional... I can add a script or something like this... Do you have an idea how can I do this, without to install additional soft?

Comment: I don't understand… Do you have your own git implementation? That is, a collection of programs that doesn't use original git but implements git protocol? In that case that implementation has to manage users. And if it doesn't — you're out of luck.

Comment: No, I just have git bare repo on our server side... Did you get?

Comment: No, you cannot have *__just__ a bare repo* — there have to be a transport level. Either you access the bare repo over ssh, or http(s), or via local filesystem (the transport then is CIFS/SMB, actually, but it doesn't matter). Both ssh and https transports have notion of users but how they're used depends on the server-side configuration which you haven't explained. So the next question is: what transport do you use and how? Can you show the result of `git remote show` (remove passwords)?

Comment: we are using local file system and `git remote show` return me `origin`...

Comment: With local file system `$USER` should be your login user name. What it really is?

Comment: I have done such thing `echo "Manual pushing to this repo is restricted ask ++ $USER ++ !!!` and there is the output from `echo`  `Manual pushing to this repo is restricted ask ++  ++ !!!`

Comment: It looks like it is empty... hmmm

Comment: What do you think? Is there a way how to make it?