# Git Privately Setup Server with GUI which includes feature of GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am working on one govt project, so i need to setup a git server privately and want to achieve all the functionality what GitHub provide mainly Sending Pull Request and merge with other repo.

Is there any way so that i can achieve all the github ui features in privately setup git on VM. I dont want to publish repository remotely it will keep it in local server only.

Note: I need all this features offline with open source or free tools.

Comment: Questions like this one should be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free GIT Server with Web GUI a la BitBucket/GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239764/free-git-server-with-web-gui-a-la-bitbucket-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+github-like+open+source+server

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the GitHub Enterprise product:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/githubs-products#github-enterprise

If you self-host it on your network it gives all the functionality of GitHub on the private network.

Comment: it is a paid service i am looking for open source or free? is any available ?

Answer (score 1):

GitBucket seems to offer all the functionality you need:

https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket

It is hosted on GitHub :-/