# Graphical Gitolite on ubuntu server

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitolite

I want to have a local git hosting on my ubuntu server so my co-workers can use it like git-hub. I mean every one can make a new repository and give access to everyone he wants.

I have previously used `gitolite` but it needs some admin to manage keys and repos. Is there any program that I can have a local git-hub?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free GIT Server with Web GUI a la BitBucket/GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239764/free-git-server-with-web-gui-a-la-bitbucket-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution, in term of setup, and authorization management, is gitea.

See https://gitea.io/en-us/

All you need is the gitea executable, and a database like PostgreSQL.

The result is a GitHub-like experience.