# How to automate git account and repository creation

Tags: git, server, backend

As a personal project I want to create my mini-github website.

I googled this, but all posts I saw are talking about setting up a server, where you have to **manually** create all users and repositories. My goal is to create a website where anyone can login and create a private repository.

Usually all posts are instructing to go to your private server, change the user and then create new repository. Only then you will be able to push your code there. I want to be able to create new repository just by clicking *new repository* button on my website, just like Github does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free GIT Server with Web GUI a la BitBucket/GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239764/free-git-server-with-web-gui-a-la-bitbucket-github)

Answer (score 0):

You can try an setup a [Gitea server](https://gitea.io/en-us/) (which is just an executable coupled with a PostreSQL database).

It does include a button for each register user to create their own repository.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15258494/29592739-fffaa4cc-8773-11e7-8b51-1f8c5f36ccc0.png]