# Local repository without remote files

Tags: git, github, repository

I maintain a few robots at work, for which I use three different virtual machines: (1) for development and test, (2) for executions and (3) for database and for hosting a website.
I access each machine using remote desktop.

I'm using Github as a repository, and my idea was, that the repository should be stored on machine number (3), and not on any servers outside of my own three machines. As far as I can tell, my files are also stored on some  Github-servers.

Is it possible to use Github, while only storing the repository on a local machine? Or do I need to use another product?

Any help is appreciated - cheers

Comment: _"my files are also stored on some Github-servers"_ - yes, but also your local repo should have a complete copy too. Once cloned, you should be able to use the local repo completely offline

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.

My problem is, that having the files on cloud servers are against company policy (after Schrems II)
So I'm looking for a find a solution, where the files are stored only on our own machines

Comment: AFAIK GitHub doesn't offer a local self-hosted tool. Try GitLab instead? Do note that git can be used on it's own completely locally without GitHub, GitLab, etc

Comment: Thanks a lot 
I did not realize that. I will look into that for a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44239764/7976758

Comment: Worth noting (though it won't affect your path to your goal): a Git repository does not exactly contain *files*. It contains *commits* (which then contain files). The key takeaway here is that you get a whole commit, or none of it, so you either have a full snapshot of *every* file, or you don't have the commit (and hence don't have those files at all).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use Github, while only storing the repository on a local machine?

Yes, that is possible with [github-Enterprise](https://github.com/pricing#compare-features) which allows hosting your own github site.

If you only want a "github-like" experience (i.e. nice web-interface), take a look at [Free GIT Server with Web GUI a la BitBucket/GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44239764/7976758) and choose one of the alternatives mentioned there. I personally have had a good experience with [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) a couple of years ago.