How could I manage(add or delete) git repos on webpage by cgit?
I'm using cgit as web front-end of git, showing my git repos. But I couldn't find out how to add/delete repos by cgit itself. Each time I want to create a new remote repo, I have to log in to my server, create it manually. It's so inconvenient.
I've read cgitrc.5.txt, but it seems to has no relative function. Hope that there's some easy way to add/delete/manage repos in cgit, otherwise I'm thinking about write it myself, but it may be too hard to a basic user...
Is there any way or projects to work with cgit and help managing repos?
By the way, how could i find some groups of cgit users, so that I could discuss with them, not asking such a foolish question here......
Additional Information:
My cgit version is commit 09d24d7, current master branch. Global cgit config(/etc/cgitrc):
css=/cgit.css
logo=/cgit.png
favicon=/favicon.ico
#footer=
virtual-root=/
enable-http-clone=0
# Smart HTTP
clone-url=https://git.qin-juan-ge-zhu.top/$CGIT_REPO_URL
root-title=勤倦阁的 Git 存储室
root-desc=Good good study, day day up!
root-readme=/var/www/cgit/README.md

enable-index-owner=1
enable-index-links=1
enable-blame=1
enable-log-filecount=1
enable-log-linecount=1
enable-commit-graph=1
enable-follow-links=1
enable-html-serving=1
enable-remote-branches=1
local-time=1

robots=noindex, nofollow

branch-sort=age
commit-sort=date
max-stats=quarter
snapshots=tar.gz zip

cache-size=1024

source-filter=/usr/local/share/cgit/filters/syntax-highlighting.py

email-filter=lua:/usr/local/share/cgit/filters/email-libravatar-korg.lua

about-filter=/usr/local/share/cgit/filters/about-formatting.sh
readme=:README.md
readme=:readme.md
readme=:README.txt
readme=:readme.txt
readme=:README
readme=:readme

mimetype.html=text/html
mimetype.gif=image/gif
mimetype.jpg=image/jpeg
mimetype.jpeg=image/jpeg
mimetype.png=image/png
mimetype.webp=image/webp
mimetype.pdf=application/pdf
mimetype.svg=image/svg+xml

remove-suffix=1

scan-path=/home/git

Besides, I'm using nginx to proxy the web page, below is my nginx configure relative to cgit:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name git.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name git.mydomain.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate somewhere;
    ssl_certificate_key somewhere;

    root /var/www/cgit;
    try_files $uri @cgit;
    client_max_body_size 10m;

    location @cgit {
        include fastcgi_params;
        # cgit's CGI script path
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/cgit/cgit.cgi;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/lib/git-core;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $uri;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $args;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST $server_name;
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git;

        if ($arg_service = git-receive-pack) {
            rewrite (/.*) /git_write/$1 last;
        }

        if ($uri ~ ^/.*/git-receive-pack$) {
            rewrite (/.*) /git_write/$1 last;
        }

        if ($arg_service = git-upload-pack) {
            rewrite (/.*) /git_read/$1 last;
        }

        if ($uri ~ ^/.*/git-upload-pack$) {
            rewrite (/.*) /git_read/$1 last;
        }
    }

    location ~ /git_read/(.*) {
        include git-http-backend.conf;
    }

    location ~ /git_write/(.*) {
        # HTTP Basic Authentication
        auth_basic "Authentication Required To Push";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/git.htpasswd;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        include git-http-backend.conf;
    }
}


"But I couldn't find out how to add/delete repos by cgit itself." cgit is a Git web-viewer and dumb HTTP service for cloning, but nothing more. It lists repositories and show their content. It allow cloning. It cannot create/delete repositories. If you want more than just viewing/cloning — you need a full-blown Git hosting solution (you can host them locally). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246093/7976758 for some examples.

"By the way, how could i find some groups of cgit users, so that I could discuss with them" Have you tried to find cgit home page? May be they list some contacts there?

@phd I've tried to use full-blown git hosting solution, but they cost too much space...Cgit really doesn't have the ability to add/delete repos, I'm just wondering some plugins or configure scripts to do it for cgit, but it seems to have no such thing.

If such plugin would exist it would need authentication to not allow any one to administer your repos. Authentication requires user management: a web UI to create/update users; which requires a database. And oops — we went from a small read-only program to a full-blown solution. No way around that, at least until you want a web-interface. Without web-interface you can write scripts that login to the server using ssh and do what you want. Authentication is done at SSH/system level, no web UI, just scripts to init or remove repositories.
